# TFS 2010 Team Build Test Run Fails With Error Regarding Test Impact Diagnostic Adapter (Two or more collectors set to collect information from IIS)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, mstest

We are using TFS for team builds and have a scenario where our application builds successfully, and all of the unit/integration tests are executed successfully, but the test run fails with the error below:

```
Error   2/16/2012 4:28:14 PM    Unable to create collection settings, diagnostics and data collection may not take place. This can be caused by having more than one instance of Microsoft Test Manager being run at the same time, or by having two or more collectors set to collect information from IIS.    Test Impact
```

The work around for this issue for the time being is to manually queue the build again, and the next build completes successfully.

For this build, the following data and diagnostic adapters are enabled in the selected test settings file:

- Code Coverage
- System Information
- Test Impact

Based on the error message, it sounds like two of the selected diagnostic adapters are conflicting with each other.  Can you not have Code Coverage and Test Impact adapters enabled at the same time?

Comment: I find this particularly frustrating, since the build shows as failed, yet the build and tests all completed, meaning the developer always asks why it failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting code coverage data does not work if you also have the test setting configured to collect IntelliTrace information. (Which you don't appear to have)

**Is your application an ASP.NET application running on IIS?** Then you need to select `Collect data from ASP.NET applications running on Internet Information Services` from the `Advanced` tab.

**Is your application an ASP.NET application running on IIS on remote client machines?** You must also use the `ASP.NET Client Proxy for IntelliTrace` and `Test Impact` data and diagnostic adapters. This, however, means that you can't use the Code Coverage adapter.

References:

- [How to: Configure Code Coverage Using Test Settings for Automated Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504821.aspx)
- [How to: Collect Data to Check Which Tests Should be Run After Code Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286598.aspx)